# Can't execute binaries double clicking on them. (chmod +x already tried)

Tags: lubuntu

This machine has been upgraded recently to Lubuntu 12.04 from 11.10. The OS is 64bit.

I had SublimeText installed, and it's the kind of software that you download it to a folder and run it simply by double-clicking on the main binary.

Now, I double click the binary file and it simply does nothing. No warnings, no errors.
Also, when I right-click the file to view its permissions, click to **Properties**, it doesn't open the file properties dialog. Without errors or warnings, either.

In Terminal, i see that the file has -rwxr-xr-x permissions.
From the Terminal I can execute the software by writing: `./sublime_text`

SublimeText was downloaded before upgrading. Now, I downloaded FileZilla to try with it, and it happens the same.

I have created a shortcut that executes `./apps/sublimetext/sublime_text` to run the app from the desktop, and this way it works.

Does anyone have any clues and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you this problem with all of your binary files or just this one ? If the problem occurs with more of your binaries, that seems to be a problem with your desktop environment. Do you know which one your are using ? Put the output of `ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/` here if you don't know. Once you'll know your desktop environment the problem must be an incorrect config file or a correct config file which doesn't match your preferences ^^

Comment: thanks epingle, apparently, it has somehow been fixed automagically in some system update (??)

Comment: Haha okay, nice ^^